# Adding Customview to UIScrollview results in stuck screen when Scrolling

Tags: ios, exception, dynamic, uiscrollview, custom-view

I am adding a custom view dynamically  and i get this exception

EXCEPTION:    ; symbol stub for: getpid

```
ITMCustomView *cView = [[ITMCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(187, 660, 400, 400)
                                                      andOrderedItem:@"dd"
                                                              andTag:self.tagNumber
                                                       withFoldArray:self.foldTypeArray
                                                       withRollArray:self.rollTypeArray];

    cView.delegate = self;
        //set properties of cView...like cView.txtName.text =@"John";

    //self.scrollView.contentSize = CGRectMake(187, 660, 400, 400).size;


    /*CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, (cView.frame.origin.y/800)*400);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:cView];

    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,scrollViewHeight);
    //CGRect newFrame = (CGRect){CGPointZero,newSize};
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:newSize];
    NSLog(@"750 the tag number is %d",self.tagNumber);
    NSLog(@"the scroll view height is %f",scrollViewHeight);
    self.currentCGRectLocation = cView.frame;*/
```

There is a lot of code above which i have commented in /* */ .Before that also i have one line

```
//self.scrollView.contentSize = CGRectMake(187, 660, 400, 400).size;
```

If i uncomment the above line it starts getting the exception. I come to this code at another point in my application. When i first launch the app this code gets called and it works fine. Now i save the records on this screen-A and go do some other calculation(basically go to another screen- B) and come back to this screen and i retrieve the saved record and display it, just display it on screen A and then i get this exception. What i have noticed is anything I do with scroll view is giving an exception. If i leave out this line

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:cView];
```

outside the comments then i can see the custom view added perfectly fine..but i loose my scrolling..the screen is stuck..So issue is sort of with scroll view i think.Please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks..

EDIT : changed to this..still does not work.

```
        ITMCustomView *cView = [[ITMCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(187, 660, 400, 400)
                                                      andOrderedItem:@"New"
                                                              andTag:self.tagNumber
                                                       withFoldArray:self.foldTypeArray
                                                       withRollArray:self.rollTypeArray];

    cView.tag =self.tagNumber;
    NSLog(@"Assigned tag is %d",cView.tag);
    cView.delegate = self;

    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, (cView.frame.origin.y/500)*400);
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:cView];

    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
    }

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,scrollViewHeight);
    //CGRect newFrame = (CGRect){CGPointZero,newSize};
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:newSize];
    NSLog(@"the scroll view height is %f",scrollViewHeight);
    self.currentCGRectLocation = cView.frame;

  for (NSObject *newObj in cView.subviews)
    {
        if ([newObj isMemberOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *txtObj = (UITextField *)newObj;
            switch (txtObj.tag) {
                case 6: //Length
                    NSLog(@"6 item value is %@",txtObj.text);
                    txtObj.text = [soliI.length stringValue]; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f",length];
                    break;
                case 7: //Width
                    NSLog(@"7 item value is %@",txtObj.text);
                    txtObj.text = [soliI.width stringValue]; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.1f",width];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if ([newObj isMemberOfClass:[UITextView class]])
        {
            UITextView *txtView = (UITextView *)newObj;
            NSLog(@"the tag is %d",txtView.tag);
            if (txtView.tag == 17)
            {
                txtView.text = soliI.specialInstructions;
            }
        }
        else if ([newObj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)newObj;
            NSLog(@"btn tag is %d",btn.tag);
            switch (btn.tag) {
                case 12:
                    [btn setTitle:@"Fold" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    break;
                case 13:
                    [btn setTitle:@"Roll" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
}
```

Comment: Why is the contentView size of your scrollView the same  size as cView's frame?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your code, what's really happening.But the thing is that contentSize of ScrollView takes two param, ie height and width which you want to scroll as it's nature of CGSize, unlike the CGRectMake as you used.

Check this, may be it'll sort your prob.

Comment: Added some code. Please check that out. It still doesn't work. I changed it to set the scroll view size to CGSize.