# UIScrollview not working even after adding setcontentsize

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, custom-view, disabled-control, cgsize

I add a custom view to my UIViewController dynamically. It adds perfectly now, no exception.But the screen is stuck. My scrollview is not functional. I got this problem earlier and people suggested use setContentSize. I did that and it worked fine. Now I have a new scenario.I have 2 screens.In screen A i save values .Then i click a bar button item on screen A and go to screen B. Here in screen B (it's a tableviewcontroller) I select one row and go back to screen A and fill the values accordingly (basically load the saved values that I saved in the beginning of the app). I fill them correctly and also add the scroll view but it is stuck.It doesn't move neither up/down. I have this code written for adding the subview and setting the scroll-view size and frame size.

```
ITMCustomView *cView = [[ITMCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(187, 660, 400, 400)
                                                         andOrderedItem:@"New"
                                                                 andTag:self.tagNumber
                                                          withFoldArray:self.foldTypeArray
                                                          withRollArray:self.rollTypeArray];

                cView.tag =self.tagNumber;
            NSLog(@"Assigned tag is %d",cView.tag);

            cView.delegate = self;

            CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, (cView.frame.origin.y/500)*400);
            [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

            [self.scrollView addSubview:cView];

            CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
            for (UIView *view in self.scrollView.subviews)
            {
                scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;
            }

            CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(320,scrollViewHeight);

            [self.scrollView setContentSize:newSize];
            NSLog(@"947 the tag number is %d",self.tagNumber);
```

I check the value of scrollViewHeight..its 3254.000..I changed it to say 4000 as someone suggested increasing height worked. So what am i doing wrong. This question follows another question of mine  [Navigating back to UIViewController from TableViewController using NSNotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044441/navigating-back-to-uiviewcontroller-from-tableviewcontroller-using-nsnotificatio#comment19404383_14044441)
If you need more info please ask.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Got mine working after I used *did* appear instead of *will* appear.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.viewMain.bounds.size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `scrollingEnabled` property on the scroll view. Unsurprisingly, it needs to be set to `YES`. If this is the case and it still doesn't work, check if the view (and its superviews) has `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES` as well. In the debugger, you can do `po [self.view recursiveDescription]` to get the view hierarchy back, that may give you some helpful information as well.

Comment: Thanks. The scrollingEnabled was set YES already. The po [self.view recursiveDescription] showed there were 174 userInteractionEnabled and all 174 were userInteractionEnabled = NO; The custom view I added has some buttons,textfields.All of them are enabled. I can press them,enter values etc.This is the first time i used po anything..so how do i proceed? This is what came up for scroll view    | <UIScrollView: 0x19c85e30; frame = (0 0; 768 960); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1be16fe0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x19c8bfd0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: Do a `print (BOOL) self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled`. It needs to be `YES` for your scrollview to work. If it is set to `YES`, I'm not sure what the problem could be, everything else seems to be fine.

Comment: @Scott.I got this on further research http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824435/uiscrollview-not-scrolling I selected scroll view on my story board. Went to File Inspector and unchecked "Use Autolayout" checkbox. Seems to work now. Will test further.